# How to access woocommerce custom taxonomies through woocommerce rest api

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

In my android app, I need to access my woocommerce inventory data using  woocommerce rest api. I am able to get all the products and their categories. Along with these I have two custom taxonomies inside Products.
For accessing categories I am making use of

```
("WOOCOMMERCE_REST_API_URL")+"products/categories";
```

I get all the categories

For accessing the list of products I make use of

```
("WOOCOMMERCE_REST_API_URL")+"products
```

But, I am not able to access my custom taxonomy "Denim Categories" using any of the endpoints.This denim Categories has a list of another set of categories.